# How to make JavaCompiler -classpath effective ? (.java on Linux)

Tags: java

I used JavaCompiler in my program and appoint a folder for tools.jar (named apiJars).
and add options
"-classpath","/home/apiJars/tools.jar:/home/jar1:/home/jar2" in .java file
When i run program on linux , it is giving below error.

```
Can't initialize javac processor due to (most likely) a class loader problem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/processing/JavacProcessingEnvironment
public class JavaCompilerTest implements Serializable
```

But its success on Windows

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the complete stack trace and include the code you run (ideally a [mre]).

Comment: thx Sauer，I've solved it.

Comment: i add tools.jar in apiJars and add dependency on pom for tools.jar